# Where can I find a list of all WeChat emoticons?

Tags: emoji, emoticons, wechat

A list of emoticons with their image, character identifier and name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found this after a lot of efforts, so I thought I should put it up somewhere more accessible. 
http://blog.csdn.net/lyq8479/article/details/9229631

This site although, has given images and not the actual spread sheet, which would have been much helpful. If anyone has a better source, please share.

Answer (score 5):

Billy 仇英华 (`@qiuyinghua`) has put all 105 original Wechat / QQ emoticons into a [Github repository](https://github.com/qiuyinghua/wechat-emoticons):

- individual PNG images (60px²)
- PNG spritesheet
- `/:` code to name mapping (JSON)
- Sketch source

[image: Wechat emoticon spritesheet]

Be aware that some of them are commonly not used in Chinese as Westerners would expect.

PS: Wechat has added additional emojis in the meantime. The GitHub repository has not been updated to reflect that yet. Also, at least the *Commando* (Soldier) emoji has been changed to not show a cigar anymore.

[image: The most important 2016 additions.]

PPS: You can extract the files yourself from the `.apk` (Andtoid app package). I have done it for you with a [preview](https://crissov.github.io/original-emoji/wechat/) or directly in a [Github repo](https://github.com/Crissov/original-emoji/tree/master/wechat).

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this answer? Also: https://github.com/Crissov/unicode-proposals/issues/359

Comment: What's the keyboard shortcut for the facepalm + weeping emoji?